# Ubuntu 12.04 trashed file disappeared

Tags: ubuntu, locate

I just trashed a very large file (250GB) on a Ubuntu 12.04, but I actually wanted to delete it. I emptied the trash, but it seems that the file is still on the disk (the free space didn't change). If i use the locate command, it says that the file is into /home/user, but it's not...

Do you know how to find the file and remove it?

Edit: I restarted the machine without results, I even tried to see if a process is using the file, but if I do:

```
sudo fuser /home/alessandro/backup.30.05.13.tar.gz 
Specified filename /home/alessandro/backup.30.05.13.tar.gz does not exist.
```

Besides, if I do:

```
locate backup.30.05.13.tar.gz
/home/alessandro/backup.30.05.13.tar.gz
```

Comment: If a program is still writing to or reading from the filehandle, it will keep taking up space on the disk until that process is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Could another process be using the file? If a process has an open filehandle then using rm will remove the name but the blocks won't be released until the last process with an open filehandle exits.

If you have an application which uses the file, is it running. Can it be restarted?

Before removing the file you could use fuser to find which processes have an open filehandle:

```
$ sudo /sbin/fuser /var/log/messages
/var/log/messages:    3004
```

Comment: I restarted the machine, so I doubt that a process is still using the file... BTW, i tried the fuser command:

sudo fuser /home/alessandro/backup.30.05.13.tar.gz
Specified filename /home/alessandro/backup.30.05.13.tar.gz does not exist.